# Python Recrusive Statement Error not Defined

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, python-2.x

I am trying to test each input then return that the number is cleared then do the math. For Example is a user inputs N instead of a number I want it to output that its not a number whereas if the user inputs 1 then I want it to move to the next function asking for a power then do the same thing and if that passes then goes to the final section which output the answer to the problem.

The program passes both the errors for the non number areas yet when it get to very last function it is telling me base nor power are defined.

Code is written in some Python2 and some Python3. All works fine though. I use python3 mostly.

[Test [Picture/Error Msg][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa1La.png)

```
    # Below we are creating the recursive statement to do the math for us. We are calling Base and Power
    # from the main function where the user Inputs the numbers.
    def pow(base, power):
        if power == 0:
            return 1
        if power == 1:
            return base
        else :
            return base * pow(base, power - 1)
    def determineBase():
        while True:
            try:
                base = int(input ('Please Enter A Base: '))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please use whole numbers only. Not text nor decimals.")
                continue
            else:
                return base

    def determinePower():

        while True:
            try:
                power = int(input ('Please Enter A Power: '))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please use whole numbers only. Not text nor decimals.")
                continue
            else:
                return power

    def main():
        determineBase()
        determinePower()
        pow(base,power)
        print("The answer to",base,"to the power of", power,"is", pow(base,power),".")
    main()
```

Comment: Try putting a gap between the recursive return and the next def also, can you please remove those lines from the screenshot so I can see the whole stack trace?

Comment: @James_Hughes nope the spaces didnt change anything. I added a different picture for you. Line 48 and line 46 is where the errors are coming

Comment: The problem isn't with your recursive function itself, see below.

Comment: Neither response really helped the function at all. It is still tossing same errors after changes are made. I am honestly not sure what I am not doing correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    determineBase()
    determinePower()
    pow(base,power)
```

Here, neither `base` nor `power` are defined. What you meant instead was to store the result from those function calls and pass those then:

```
def main():
    base = determineBase()
    power = determinePower()
    pow(base, power)
```

Comment: still solved nothing unless the whole program is wrong

Comment: *“Solved nothing”* means what exactly? What is your exact error message and stack trace?

Comment: The message was posted in initial post under the image. Declaring the variables still outputs same issue.

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t believe that. There is no way this would produce the same error message when you modify the code in the question in that way.

Comment: the code is above. Input it and see. If your not willing to help then avoid commenting getting free rep for commenting. I asked for assistance.

Comment: Yes, the exact code from the question with the fix from my answer is working fine for me. That’s why I don’t believe that you are still seeing the *exact same error*.

Comment: maybe I just typed in the wrong solution then. I deleted whole code then readded mine plus the changes above and well guess it does work. Maybe I saved it wrong when I continued to try and play with it to figure out issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't inside the recursive function, it's inside your main function.

The problem is arising due to the fact that you are passing `base` as an argument to the `pow()` function without defining the variable base first (the same would subsequently be true for `power`).

In other words you need something along the lines of:

```
def main():
    base = determineBase()
    power = determinePower()
    pow(base,power) #this line could probably be removed
    print("The answer to",base,"to the power of", power,"is", pow(base,power),".")
```

As currently, you're not storing the values of these two functions.